# GASでwordpressのパスワード保護ページにログインし、スクレイピングする方法

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, web-scraping

GASでwordpressのパスワード保護ページにログインし、表示される内容をスクレイプしたいのですが、ログインがうまくできません。

```
<?php if( !post_password_required( $post->ID ) ) : ?>
  //下記のブロック要素をスクレイプしたい
  <div class="hg1">
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo get_the_password_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

試したこととしては

```
function testLogin(){
  //下記はvar LOGIN_URL = "https://hghg/wp-login.php"や固定ページのパスなど色々変更しましたがうまくいきませんでした。
  //Request URLなども参照し行いましたがここが間違えているかもしれません。
  //hghgは例です。
  var LOGIN_URL = "https://hghg/wp-login.php?action=postpass";
  
  // POSTデータ
  var payload_data = {
    //Chromeの開発者ツールのNetwork->Form Dataを参照し設定しました。
    "post_password":"保護ページにログインするパスワード",
    "Submit": "確定",
  };
  
  // POSTオプション
  var post_options = {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    payload: payload_data,
    followRedirects: false
  };
  
  // POSTリクエスト
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(LOGIN_URL, post_options);

  // レスポンスヘッダーからcookieを取得
  var cookies = response.getHeaders()["Set-Cookie"];
  
  // ログインで認証されたcookieをヘッダーで使用
  var headers = { Cookie: cookies }; 
  var get_options = {
    method: "get",
    headers: headers,
    followRedirects: true,
  };
  var SCRAPING_URL = "https://hghg/対象の固定ページ/";
  
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(SCRAPING_URL, get_options);
  var content = response.getContentText("UTF-8");
　Logger.log(content)
}
```

と上記のようにCookieの情報を取得し行おうとしました。

期待する結果としては、

```
<div class="hg1">
</div>
```

を含む文字列を取得したいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ログインがうまくできないとは具体的にどういう現象でしょうか？期待する結果だけではなく、実行してみて出てきた予想外の結果とレスポンスを知りたいです（404が返ってきた、認証に失敗した、ログインはできたが保護ページの内容を見られないetc）。

Comment: 申し訳ありません、記載し忘れておりました。
最初に保護ページのURL自体（https://hghg/対象の固定ページ/）を上記のLOGIN_URLに指定して実行してみた結果、エラーは発生しなかったのですが、保護している内容が見受けられませんでした。
ですので、リクエストURLを指定しなければいけないと思い、https://hghg/wp-login.php?action=postpassをLOGIN_URLに指定しました。
すると403（認証に失敗）が返ってきました。なので、payload_dataにて指定している形式がおかしいのかと思ったのですが、Form Data以外に指定するものが思いつかず、現状に至ります。